# What is the recommended method to synchronize access to an object in Java for Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, mutex

I have objects that I need to display in 1 thread and also continuously update in a 2. thread. Is there a recommended way for Java on Android to handle this kind of access (lock/unlock) to an object like a mutex or something like that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to synchronize between threads then it's the same as for Java on anywhere else: there is no special android.concurrent package.

Android has some classes that help with concurrency in general like Handler & AsyncTask but those are more about switching thread contexts. Still they might be the answer to your question: if used properly you may not need to synchronize.

Comment: Handler and AsyncTask are definitely going to be the way for HardCoder to go since Dalvik is very touchy about allowing you to access the View hierarchy from anywhere outside the main UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lock implementation in Android (java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock) "A lock is a tool for controlling access to a shared resource by multiple threads".  Here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html.  Multithreading UI access is a bit different.